# Primefaces Right to Left support

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Could anyone please point some css tweaks for combo-box, menus and menubar css code to get primefaces to work with Arabic.

Comment: It is to do with setting the locale. What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Please check this image,[link](http://i.imgur.com/1dyWm.png) The combobox triangle shall be towards left, while set to Arabic locale and dir to RTL, and Also I don't currently have all labels in Arabic, but the one which I have is not displayed properly.

Comment: stackoverflow itself has lot of posts on this topic. What steps are followed by you to achieve arabisation is not spelled out. To start with, please refer to http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Answer (score 0):

As I know, unfortunately primefaces don't support RTL at the moment (3.4)
but they told that they will add support for RTL starting from version 3.5

Check this tweet from primefaces leader.
https://twitter.com/primefaces/status/232541151771627520